# Split action types into different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a excel sheet with different action types such as dividends, annual general meetings and so on..

Is there a way to write a vba macro that takes all the action types and puts them into separate sheet within the workbook ? Also the header such as date time  should be included in all of the sheets. I am kind of struggling with this atm as I am new to VBA: I have a screen shot of the excel sheet..

[image]

Again thanks in advance.

I have the code which sorts for dividends however I am struggling to get the actions into a list and then go through the list and create new sheets.

```
Sub SortActions()
 Dim i&, k&, s$, v, r As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set r = [index(a:a,match("###start",a:a,),):index(a:a,match("###end",a:a,),)].Offset(, 6)
    k = r.Row - 1
    v = r
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If LCase$(v(i, 1)) = "dividend" Then
            s = s & ", " & i + k & ":" & i + k
        End If
    Next
    s = Mid$(s, 3)
    If Len(s) Then
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        With Sheets.Add(, ws)
            ws.Range(s).Copy .[a1]
            Rows("1:1").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Sheets("20140701_corporate_action_servi").Select
            Rows("2:2").Select
            Selection.Copy2
            Range("C32").Select
            Sheets("Sheet11").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is definitely possible. You should start out by recording macros to see what code it generates and try to go from there. We're not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Public Sub CopyActionTypes()
    Dim i&, k&, key, v, r As Range, ws As Worksheet, d As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = [index(a:a,match("###start",a:a,),):index(a:a,match("###end",a:a,),)].Offset(, 6)
    If Err = 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        k = r.Row + 1
        v = r
        Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        d.CompareMode = 1
        For i = 1 To UBound(v)
            key = v(i, 1)
            If Len(key) Then
                If Not d.Exists(key) Then d.Add key, k & ":" & k
                d(key) = d(key) & Replace(",.:.", ".", i)
            End If
        Next
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        For Each key In d.Keys
            If LCase$(key) <> "action_type" Then
                With Sheets.Add(, ws.Parent.Sheets(ws.Parent.Sheets.Count))
                    .Name = key
                    GetRangeUnion(d(key), ws).Copy .[a1]
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetRangeUnion(s As String, ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim i&, v, r As Range
    v = Split(s, ",")
    Set r = ws.Range(v(0))
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        Set r = Union(r, ws.Range(v(i)))
    Next
    Set GetRangeUnion = r
End Function
```

As an aside, try to not select anything from code during your macros. This is a best practice and one of many ways to optimize code.